# String function in for loops

Tags: c++

```
for( it = str.begin(); it != str.end() && isspace( *it ); it++ ) ;
str.erase(str.begin(), it );
```

What exactly is this loop is doing?

Comment: The string function (sic) is not a part of the loop. All the work is done in condition and increment parts of the loop. The `erase` is called once after the loop is done.

Comment: Given the `begin()` and `end()`, this is *not* C# so why is it tagged as such?

Comment: It's *C++*, not *C#*

Answer (score 6):

```
for( it = str.begin(); it != str.end() && isspace( *it ); it++ ) ;
```

This line positions an iterator at the beginning of a string (`str.begin()`). The condition `it != str.end() && isspace( *it )` says in plain english "while the end of the string has not been reached AND the current character is a space, increment the iterator."

Next

```
str.erase(str.begin(), it );
```

This erases the part of the string from its begin to the iterator. In clear terms, *it trims any whitespace at the beginning of a string*.

EDIT : Please read the comment below, it adds useful information to the answer.

Comment: Except that `isspace( *it )` is undefined behavior.  (The "correct" way to skip leading white space is `it = std::find_if( str.begin(), str.end(), []( unsigned char ch ) { ! isspace( ch ); } );`.  (I'll have to thank Alf for the trick of declaring the lambda to take an `unsigned char`, and thus avoiding the cast which would otherwise be necessary.)

Answer (score 4):

This code is too clever for its own good - there are good reasons for not condensing code too much vertically.
Loop-confusion is one of them.

Rewriting a bit

```
for( it = str.begin(); it != str.end() && isspace(*it); it++ )
    ;
str.erase(str.begin(), it );
```

or, equivalently

```
for( it = str.begin(); it != str.end() && isspace(*it); it++ )
{
    // Personally, I always put an "intentionally left empty" comment inside these.
}
str.erase(str.begin(), it );
```

makes it clear that the `erase` is *outside* the loop.

Rewriting the loop using `while`

```
it = str.begin();
while (it != str.end() && isspace(*it))
{
    it++;
}
str.erase(str.begin(), it );
```

makes it more obvious that it first locates the first non-space character in the string and then erases everything before it, i.e. trims leading whitespace.

(I prefer the `while` form myself.)

Comment: I especially like how you've noted the weirdness of the loop, and suggested how to make it *very clear* there's nothing actually going on inside.

Answer (score 0):

This code des two things.

The first one finds the first character in the string, which is not a white-space:

```
for( it = str.begin(); it != str.end() && isspace( *it ); it++ ) ;
```

The second removes all the characters till that character:

```
str.erase(str.begin(), it );
```

The combination of them: the code removes the white-space characters in the beginning of the string :)